# How do I call this maptree function in Scala?

Tags: scala, currying

I am rather new to Scala and I have been given this function

```
def map_tree[A,B](f: A => B)(tree: Tree[A]): Tree[B] =
  tree match {
    case Leaf(value) => Leaf(f (value))
    case Node(value , l, r) => Node(f (value), map_tree (f) (l), map_tree (f) (r))
}
```

Here is my Tree class and Leaf and Node definitions

```
abstract class Tree[+A]
case class Leaf[A](value: A) extends Tree[A]
case class Node[A](value: A, left: Tree[A], right: Tree[A]) extends Tree[A]
```

How would I call this map_tree function within another function?

For example if I had this function

```
def add_n(t: Tree[Int], n: Int) : Tree[Int] =
```

How can I call map_tree in it to cause it to add n to every element in the tree?

```
def add_n(t: Tree[Int], n: Int) : Tree[Int] =
    map_tree(what do I input here)?
```

I have tried calling it like this:

```
  map_tree( t => t+n)(t)
```

But it is telling me "Invalid parameter type". I think that is not what the input should be, but I'm not sure what I am supposed enter in the first parentheses in map_tree

Comment: Please create a [MCVE] of your problem.

Comment: Ok, I have tried to do this!

Comment: You're not too far from such an example. Add your types - `Leaf`, `Node` and `Tree`.

Comment: Oh sorry ok will do

Comment: Try, map_tree( t: Int => t+n)(t)

Comment: When I try that it says "not found: type +"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I get a different error message (in Scala 2.11.8):

```
scala> abstract class Tree[+A]
defined class Tree

scala>   case class Leaf[A](value: A) extends Tree[A]
defined class Leaf

scala>   case class Node[A](value: A, left: Tree[A], right: Tree[A]) extends Tree[A]
defined class Node

scala> def map_tree[A,B](f: A => B)(tree: Tree[A]): Tree[B] =
     |   tree match {
     |     case Leaf(value) => Leaf(f (value))
     |     case Node(value , l, r) => Node(f (value), map_tree (f) (l), map_tree (f) (r))
     | }
map_tree: [A, B](f: A => B)(tree: Tree[A])Tree[B]

scala> def add_n(t: Tree[Int], n: Int) : Tree[Int] = map_tree( t => t+n)(t)
<console>:17: error: missing parameter type
       def add_n(t: Tree[Int], n: Int) : Tree[Int] = map_tree( t => t+n)(t)
```

Anyway, this is just type inference failing you, as happens sometimes. It works fine if you give it the type args explicitly:

```
scala> def add_n(t: Tree[Int], n: Int): Tree[Int] = map_tree[Int, Int](t => t + n)(t)
add_n: (t: Tree[Int], n: Int)Tree[Int]
```

Comment: This also solves the type inference issue: `def add_n(t: Tree[Int], n: Int) : Tree[Int] = map_tree((x: Int) => x + n)(t) ` The compiler knows that `n` is an Int but that info and the plus operand are not enough to infer the type of `x`. So the type of `x` has to be explicit.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add on @Chris_Martin's answer, here is a precise **explanation** of the type inference problem:

- For a lambda to be type checked without providing parameter types, the lambda's expected type has to be known. For example, you can write `val f: Int => Int = _ + 1` but not `val f = _ + 1` even if you use `f` later as a `Int => Int` (Scala's type inference is *local*).
- Argument lists in method calls are type checked independently, from left to right. So to check `map_tree(t => t+n)(t)`, Scala first checks `map_tree(t => t+n)`, but at this point it has not decided what the `A` type parameter should be, so there is no expected type for the `t => t+n` lambda, resulting in the error you get.

**Solution:**

You could simply swap the parameter lists in `map_tree`, as in:

```
def map_tree[A,B](tree: Tree[A])(f: A => B): Tree[B] = ...
```

Then you can just call it like `map_tree(t)(t => t+n)`, because Scala will first type check `map_tree(t)`, inferring `Int` for `A` and thus being able to type the lambda correctly later on.